# Difference Import Behaviour

Tags: magento2

What is the difference between \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND and \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_ADD_UPDATE in Magento 2?

Answer (score 1):

I would say in the first case, ne products and data are always appended. In the second, data with matching keys (SKUs) triggers an update.